# How are cases of wrong data published to the blockchain handled?

Tags: error, bug, immutability

How are cases of wrong data published to the blockchain handled? Let's say I am Defi protocol or even an oracle...and shit always happens, there was a mistake somewhere and the wrong data get published on the blockchain.

How are such scenario handled? Because I can imagine such mistakes happens, because no human or process is free from errors

And since the blockchain is immutable, how are such situations handled?

Bonus points for sharing references to real life situations where such errors happened and how it was handled :)

Answer (score 0):

In a `blockchain`, once data is published to the blockchain, it becomes `immutable` and cannot be changed. Therefore, if `wrong data` is published to the blockchain, it cannot be directly corrected or removed

However, there is a way of changing data on the blockchain by making the smart contract in such a way that the data can be updated by certain previlleged users such as admin/owner